# how to check codeigniter old password?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new in codeigniter. I want to change password and match it with old password. If it gets matched then user can enter new password.
my view file is

```
<div class="modal-body">
<?php echo form_open('textarea/changePass')?>
<input class="span5" type="password" name="oldPass" placeholder="Old Password" required/>
<input class="span5" type="password" name="newPass" placeholder="New Password" required/>
<input class="span5" type="password" name="renewPass" placeholder="Re-type New Password" required/>


    <input type="submit" value="Change" class="btn btn-primary btn-inverse" />
    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Cancel</button>
     <?php echo form_close()?>
     </div>
```

my controller file is:

```
function changePass(){
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('oldPass','Old Password','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('newPass','New Password','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('renewPass','Retype Password','required|matches[newPass]');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
        $ref = $this->input->server('HTTP_REFERER', TRUE);
        redirect($ref, 'location');

    }else{
        $query = $this->mod1->checkOldPass(md5($this->input->post('oldPass')));
        echo "sdgsggs";
        if($query){
            $query = $this->mod1->saveNewPass(md5($this->input->post('newPass')));
            if($query){
                $this->session->sess_destroy();
                $data['error']='Password Change Successfully. Please login to Continue.';
                $this->load->view('first',$data);

            }else{
                $ref = $this->input->server('HTTP_REFERER', TRUE);
                redirect($ref, 'location');

            }
        }
    }
}
```

my model file is:

```
    function checkOldPass($oldPass){
    $this->db->where('username',$this->session->userdata('username'));
    $query=$this->db->get('members');
    if($query->num_rows>0){
        $row=$query->row();
        if($oldPass == $row->password){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}

function saveNewPass($new_pass){
    $data = array(
        'password' => $new_pass
    );
    $this->db->where('username', $this->session->userdata('username'));
    $query = $this->db->update('members', $data);
    if($query){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

I am having problem in checking the old password. Its returning false. I saved my password in md5 format. please help me guys. Please dnt b harsh. Thank you.

Comment: What is the `length` of your password field in table?

Comment: have you tried to debug your checkOldPass() function at all? `print_r($oldPass); print_r($row); print_r($row->password);` could shed some light as to what's happenning

Comment: paasword is in in checkold password $row->password is not getting the password

Comment: it has been solved. thanks for your effort

Answer (score 0):

Just for debugging purposes, try this:

```
function checkOldPass($oldPass){
    $this->db->where('username', $this->session->userdata('username'));
    $query=$this->db->get('members');
    /* For debugging */
    $row    = $query->row();
    echo "Old Password : ".$oldPass."<br>";
    echo "From DB : ".$row->password."<br>";
    die;
    /* For debugging */
    if($query->num_rows>0){
        $row=$query->row();
        if($oldPass == $row->password){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I checked it but its not changing the password

Comment: solved the problem. md5 is case sensitive. thank you for your efforts.